# Log4j2 Silence specific package

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, log4j2, jersey-2.0

I've just updated to Log4. Now i have some small issues configurating my new setup.

The log4j2.xml is quite small and simple, but i'm not sure how i can disable logs (or at least set them to ERROR) for all jersey packages.

Here's my log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="FILE" fileName="/logs/m2m/error.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
        </File>
        <Async name="ASYNC">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" />
        </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.glassfish.jersey.servlet" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC" />
        </Logger>   
        <Root level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And here's the log-output i try to silence:

```
Jan 24, 2014 8:21:12 AM org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent filterFormParameters
WARNING: A servlet request to the URI #### contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the format of the output I suspect that the log output shown above is actually produced by JUL (java.util.logging) and not by log4j.

It is possible to route calls made to the java.util.logging API to the log4j2 implementation. Your log4j2 configuration (which looks correct) should then filter out WARN-level log events emitted by any class in the `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet` package.

This involves adding a few more jars to the classpath: see the [FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#which_jars).

Comment: I've tried to add the jul-to-slf4j lib but it didn't change anything. Here's which libs i actually have in my lib folder: log4j-1.2-api-2.0.jar log4j-api.jar log4j-slf4j-impl.jar log4j.jar slf4j-api.jar jul-to-slf4j-1.7.5.jar

Comment: If log4j.jar is the old log4j-1.2.x it should be removed. Furthermore you seem to be missing the log4j-core-2.0.jar.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. i've removed the version-number 2.0 from all these libs. So it's easier to update them without the need of changing the build-path again.

I was able to solve me issue. The problem was that a sub-library we use internal had the slf4j-simple lib which was used. this made some issues. but your answer is correct. thanks

Comment: Ok i've tried it now on my server (tomcat) and there it isn't working. I'm out of ideas. Do you have any other hint?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do with Logback, here I explain how to do it:

[Excessive warning messages from Jersey 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23808594/616550)