# Excessive warning messages from Jersey 2.x

Tags: java, glassfish, jersey, jersey-2.0

I keep getting these warning messages from any POST operation with APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED form data:

```
A servlet request to the URI (local request URI) contains form parameters in the request body   but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected.
```

I've traced this down to org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent:

```
        if (!form.asMap().isEmpty()) {
            containerRequest.setProperty(InternalServerProperties.FORM_DECODED_PROPERTY, form);

            if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.WARNING)) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, LocalizationMessages.FORM_PARAM_CONSUMED(containerRequest.getRequestUri()));
            }
        }
```

So, if there's any form data, it will always print this warning.  Am I doing something wrong as filling up the log with warnings for normal operations doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Logback with Slf4j, and you only should add "**jul-to-slf4j**" as dependency and configure it in logback.xml.

In *pom.xml*:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>  
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>${logback.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

To redirect jul messages to logback, add this inside  in *logback.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>

    <appender name="OUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    ...

    <logger name="org.glassfish.jersey.servlet" level="ERROR" />

</configuration>
```

Setting level for **org.glassfish.jersey.servlet** to ERROR lets you avoid warning messages in log files.